# Queen with Knight capabilities

Tags: rules, chess-variants, history, unorthodox-pieces

I find it interesting that the Queen can move with the same capabilities as the Rook and the Bishop, but cannot 'jump' or move like the Knight, I understand that this would overpower the queen but theoretically could make the game more interesting, quicker, or more strategic.

I want to know, what are the practical implications of giving the Queen this extra move-set?

Are there any obscure chess variations where this is allowed?

Comment: One practical implication would be that it could checkmate an enemy king at the edge of the board without help from any other piece.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are there any obscure chess variations where this is allowed?

There are. One name for the queen+knight hybrid piece is the [Amazon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_%28chess%29). As noted in the Wikipedia entry on the Amazon piece I just linked to, the Amazon appears in the variant sometimes called [Turkish Great Chess](http://www.chessvariants.org/historic.dir/indiangr1.html), a game played on a 10x10 board and featuring besides the Amazon (which is typically called a Giraffe in Turkish Great Chess) two other [fairy chess pieces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_chess_piece): a bishop+knight piece (Vizir) and a rook+knight piece (War Machine). (Those sorts of pieces appear under yet different names in the [Capablanca Chess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capablanca_chess) and [Seirawan Chess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seirawan_chess) variants as well.)

[image: Turkish Great Chess]

A second variant that is mentioned in the Amazon Wikipedia entry is [The Maharaja and the Sepoys](http://www.chessvariants.org/unequal.dir/maharaja.html), which provides a severe test for the might of the Amazon: namely, it pits a lone Amazon (Maharaja) against a standard chess army on an 8x8 board. An Amazon is capable of checkmating a king by itself, and that is its objective, while the standard army is tasked with checkmating the very mobile Amazon.

[image: Maharaja and the Sepoys]